# Point to front-end application as a dependency in in package.json

Tags: npm, phoenix-framework, elm

My team is working on a phoenix/elm application, and have decided to keep the two projects in separate repos, and to 'point' to the elm application from the phoenix app. This is sort of new terrain for me, and I've been looking into different ways to accomplish this. One way that has occurred to me is to point to the elm app from the phoenix app's package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
  ...
  "elmApp": "myProject/elmApp#master"
},
...
```

I've run `npm install`, which seems to have worked. However, I'm not really sure where to go from here... how to access the javascript compiled by Elm and include it in my phoenix template.

Comment: Is `myProject/elmApp` on github? (no need to point to the actual name)

Comment: I set up by build script to copy the end product into /priv/static within phoenix

Comment: Yes, it is on github. How can you point to it without pointing to the name? 

A build script that finds a repo on github?